# Disabling Google Smart Lock but still save passwords

Tags: google-chrome, security, passwords, password-management

I use Chrome on Windows 7. Every time the browser asks to save my password it's saved in the cloud unless Google Smart Lock is off but it this case I have to reenter the password each time I log in to a web site. I have no idea when they introduced such a nice "feature" but I do not want Google to know my passwords. Instead, I want the old behavior back - when my passwords a stored locally on a machine where I run Chrome. How can I do it?

Another related question is how Google stores passwords in their cloud? Can I be sure my passwords won't be known if I delete them on Smart Lock screen or I have to change my typical passwords to a new one on all web sites I use?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to disable Google Smart Lock again as follows:

1. Enter the browser settings by selecting the three-dot menu at the upper-right corner and then choosing "Settings".
2. Go down to "Passwords and forms" option and select "Manage passwords".
   Once in, choose "Offer to save passwords off." Proceed to also disable "Auto Sign-in".
3. Clear browsing history to remove all traces of your passwords from Chrome.

I find it on Cyclonis blog and have made it on my Windows 8.1.